# Balancing octane combustion reaction for internal combustion engine

Tags: stoichiometry, combustion

I am trying to balance out the equation for combustion of octane in $120\,\%$ of excess air with products $\ce{CO2},$ $\ce{H2O},$ $\ce{N2},$ and $\ce{O2}$:

$$\ce{C8H18 + 1.2$a$(O2 + 3.76 N2) -> $b$ CO_2 + $c$ H2O + $d$ O2 + $e$ N2}$$

My approach was as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
&\ce{C}: & b &= 8 \\
&\ce{H}: & 2c &= 18 \\
&\ce{O}: & 2b + c + 2d &= 2\times 1.2a \\
&\ce{N}: & e &= 3.76\times 1.2a
\end{align}
$$

However, I think somewhere in my steps there's something I am not doing correctly as I am unable to determine $a$ with the system of equations I tried developing.

Comment: Octane combusted in air yields carbon dioxide plus water. The nitrogen in air does nothing, unless you are in, e.g., an internal combustion engine. So ignore nitrogen.

Comment: This is for an internal combustion engine.

Comment: I have found the already balanced equation online, it includes all those reactants and all those products, I am trying how to figure out the balancing aspect.

Comment: A chemical equation must not mention substances that are not transformed, like $\ce{N2}$and part of $\ce{O2}$ here.

Comment: Maurice I understand what you are trying to explain; however, these reaction is written including O2 and N2 and the balancing process was done including them. If you google the reaction you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: If this actually is in the context of chemical engineering, then this should be mentioned in the question. Ideally the whole exercise should be quoted verbatim with a citation. From the chemical point of view, there really is not much use in including these; and for the problem at hand the best solution would be to strip the exercise down to the actual reaction that happens then include whatever additional information what was given.

Comment: It is remarkable that many textbooks and lectures select the combustion reaction of octane of all the possible combustion reactions of gasoline to show the principle of combustion. Note that internal combustion engines actually do not run on octane. Typical gasoline contains less than 1 % octane. See also my answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/63299/101286) about common misconceptions related to octane.

Comment: It is not clear whether you are trying to represent an idealised reaction of octane or a realistic reaction from an engine. You show nitrogen but not any reaction products involving it (which just overcomplicates things *unless* you intended to include reactions producing nitrogen oxides). If your want the latter, you won't get a simple equation as the side reactions are highly sensitive to the detailed reaction conditions.

Comment: Nitrogen is included in the reaction as it is carried out with theoretical air which is (O2 3.76N2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the reaction is done in excess of air, you can assume complete combustion and accordingly you should break down the reaction to only this.

Apparently the question demands an answer in the following form:
$$\ce{C8H18 + 1.2$a$ (O2 + 3.76 N2) -> b CO2 + c H2O + d O2 + e N2},$$
however, this is the same as
$$\begin{multline}
\ce{C8H18 + x O2 + 0.2x O2 + (1.2$x$\times3.76) N2}\\
\ce{-> y CO2 + z H2O + 0.2x O2 + (1.2$x$\times3.76) N2},
\end{multline}$$
which is the same as
$$\ce{C8H18 + x O2 -> y CO2 + z H2O},$$
just more complicated.

From there you can form
\begin{align}
\ce{C}: && y &= 8\\
\ce{H}: && z &= \frac{1}{2}\times18 = 9\\
\ce{O}: && 2 x &= 2y + z \Longleftrightarrow x = 12.5.
\end{align}

Now you can obviously go back to the requested form:
$$\ce{C8H18 + 15 (O2 + 3.76 N2) -> 8 CO2 + 9 H2O + 2.5 O2 + 56.4 N2}.$$

Comment: (+1) And, of course, no internal combustion engine was involved, even putatively: no nitrogen oxides were produced. As well, the problem did not involve considerations of thermodynamics, e.g., the heating up of the nitrogen in the air.

Answer (score -2):

Key things I did not consider properly:

120% of excess air, which means 0.2 of oxygen goes free, this changes my equation to:

$$\ce{C8H18 + 1.2$a$ (O2 + 3.76 N2) -> b CO2 +c H2O + 0.2a O2 + e N2} $$

So,

\begin{align}
\ce{C}:&& b  &= 8\\
\ce{H}:&& 2c &= 18\\
\ce{O}:&& 2b + c + 2(0.2) &= 2\times1.2a \implies a = 12.5\\
\ce{N}:&& e &= 3.76\times1.2a = 56.4
\end{align}

Comment: This is exactly the same as $\ce{C8H18 + x O2 -> y CO2 + z H2O}$, just more complicated.

Comment: The point was for me to understand how to workout the problem using this kind of forms. I still need to write down the balanced from of the more complicated expression.